# Sending ordered broadcast to default Android / HTC Music Player does not work

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I am sending an ordered broadcast to specific media players, so that I can play/pause/ff/rewing etc using a remote control.

```
private void sendbroadcast(int keyEvent) {
      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);     
      String selectedMediaPlayer =  Common.get(context, SONR.APP_PACKAGE_NAME, "MEDIAPLAYERNOTFOUND");
      Log.d("BROADCAST PLAYER", selectedMediaPlayer);
      i.setPackage(selectedMediaPlayer);

      synchronized (this) {
         i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyEvent));
         context.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

         i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyEvent));
         context.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
      }
   }
```

This works for most media players. But for some reason when I send an ordered broadcast to `com.android.music`nothing happens.

Wondering how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the music player in android.org, should they abort ordered broadcasts. Now I know.